# didReceiveResponse delegate method in Restkit 0.20

Tags: ios, request, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using Restkit 0.20  for my project. I make a request like this.

```
NSData *postData  = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path relativeToURL:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    RKObjectManager *manager = [[RestKit sharedDataManager] objectManager];
    RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [manager managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request managedObjectContext:manager.managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation1, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
             block ([mappingResult array]);

        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation1, NSError *error) {
            RKLogDebug(@"Failure %@",error.debugDescription);
            block (error);
        }];
```

After competing mapping operation, i am returning an array using block. I need to get a response in a delegate to use for some operation. Is there any method similar to didReceiveResponse in Restkit0.10 and also i am aware of this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restkit/TrWH5GR-gFU in which blake mentioned that we have full control over the headers via the NSURLRequest object. But how can i make use of NSURLRequest when i am using RKManagedObjectRequestOperation. can anyone post some example.

Thanks

Comment: You already have a request : `NSMutableURLRequest` (which is the mutable subclass of `NSURLRequest`)...

Comment: But i am using RKmangedObjectRequestOperation instead of     NSURLConnection. how can i get the delegate function to load response.

Answer (score 1):

if you just need response.statuscode you can get it.
in restkit success block we have two parameters (RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result)

to get response you can use this.

```
operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a request : `NSMutableURLRequest` (which is the mutable subclass of `NSURLRequest`), so any required headers can be set there.

When the `success` callback is called it includes the `RKObjectRequestOperation`, you can request the `HTTPRequestOperation` (an instance of `RKHTTPRequestOperation`), from which you can request `response` (an instance of `NSHTTPURLResponse`).

---

Based on your updated description you would need to subclass `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` and override `performMappingOnResponse:` in order to insert your additional processing before calling `super`.

Comment: Thanks Wain. But at that time response will be mapped with DB. i need to get the response before response is mapped with DB. In Restkit 0.10, we have didLoadObjects and didLoadResponse delegate methods. like that do we have any other delegate method to check the response. Actually my requirement was if i have a successful respone, make some DB operation and then map the response.